# How to replace icons in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, gnome, linux-mint

I have a problem with linux mint. The icons, I am trying to genericize my computer, with Tux logos. But some way or another, the icons reverted to linuxmint after a reboot (files were overwritten with the mint logo...). I really dislike this. I need to know how to gut linuxmint components and possibly do an in-place swap to another distro.

It looked like this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=-0icCwQVtFE

But as soon as I rebooted, the tux menu icons change to linuxmint.

Answer (score 2):

Linux mint is overwriting other theme icons using the images in this directory :

```
/usr/share/linuxmint/common/artwork/logos
```

Just overwrite those images with the images of your choosing, with the same sizes.

The side effect is now every other theme will use your chosen images for distribution logo.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Others > Advanced Settings > Themes and select the Icon theme from the Dropdown